# Disable info window shadow in google maps (v2)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there any way to disable the automatically generated shadow for the info window for a marker?

I'm trying to get around the bug reported at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=69bcc3217ee1ac68&hl=en where the shadow has big black marks around it that obscure the view of the map when viewed in IE 8 at any zoom level other than 100%.

Comment: Looks ok in my IE8, no black marks at any zoom level. Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, for IE 8 only, you'll have to traverse the dom, find the shadow images (iws3.png), and hide them. If you have jQuery at your disposal, then it's as simple as

```
$('img[src$="iws3.png"]').hide();
```

after the map has loaded.

Or, if you don't have jQuery, something like...

```
var i, imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (/iws3\.png/.test(imgs[i].src)) {
        imgs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

P.S. @Crescent Fresh, here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Wheird, thank you. Any chance you have a link with an affected map? I still can't reproduce in my IE8.

Comment: http://www.eeaa.com.au/venue.php (it's the link in the first response to the bug report that John Smith linked to).

Comment: Thank you, missed that before. Still looks good to me, at all zoom levels. Tested in native IE 8.0.6001.18702. XP SP 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is very simple solution to your problem: hide both shadow layers. This way you can be sure that all objects are hidden (even those added after hide)

```
var map = GMap2(...);
...
var pane;

//contains the info window shadow image
pane = map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE);
pane.style.display = "none";

//contains the marker shadow images
pane = map.getPane(G_MAP_MARKER_SHADOW_PANE);
pane.style.display = "none";
```

Yet another question would be how to detect conditions under which layers should be hidden...

Answer (score 0):

But in V3 you don't use GMap2

I managed to disable the shadows with the following css:

```
div.gmnoprint div img 
{
    display: none;
}
```

In V2 you had:

```
map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE).style.display = "none";
map.getPane(G_MAP_MARKER_SHADOW_PANE).style.display = "none";
```

Seems that in V3 you can only access the panes in [OverlayView](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-js-api-v3@googlegroups.com/msg03859.html)  (?)

Comment: gmnoprint is used for a lot of things (not just shadows) that shouldn't show up in the printable version.